# From android.media.Image to Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using Android Camera2 API to acquire frames from the camera. I can get an ImageReader that reads Image objects with the acquireLatestImage() method.

Since I need to process the acquired frames, I have to convert each Image object into a Mat object. I suppose this is a quite common problem, so I expected to find a convenient OpenCV method to do that. However I didn't find any.

Do you have an idea on how to get Mat objects from the camera frames with Android Camera2?
Thanks

Comment: If it's possible to convert android.media.Image to a Bitmap first, then there's [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html) but there's a chance doing this might affect your processing time significantly.

Comment: Also, take a look at how a byte array is retrieved from android.media.Image in this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L790). The source code for OpenCV's JavaCameraView also shows how a byte array is converted to a mat through this [method](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android%2BJavaCameraView.java#L285). Do note that this is all theoretical, I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what [ImageFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html) you set for your ImageReader class. This code below assumes that it's using the JPEG format.

```
Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

Mat buf = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
buf.put(0, 0, bytes);

// Do note that Highgui has been replaced by Imgcodecs for OpenCV 3.0 and above
Mat mat = Highgui.imdecode(buf, IMREAD_COLOR);

image.close();
```

Do note that imdecode is quite slow. I'm not entirely sure but I think [YUV_420_888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888) would be faster to convert to a Mat object, but I haven't figured out how to do it myself. I saw this [post](http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/6ededc236fe4a68bda28f9aa26e9d0f8-81af1e306e0a180e0bd5d2b3cd854654) attempt the YUV conversion to a Mat,